# python error : ValueError: could not convert string to float: (maybe system env related)

Tags: python, version

I have simple python code to read data file and plot graph.
It works well in previous system. My system was crashed, I setting another system with higher ubuntu version.
When I run script, I faced error which is not exist in previous system.
Previous system was broken, I cannot compare in detail.

Code

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import csv
 import sys
 def analyze():

     datafile = sys.argv[1]
     pieces = []
     with open(datafile, 'rt') as f:
          data = csv.reader(f,delimiter = '\t')
          for d in data:
            pieces.append(d)

    x = [op for op, response, interval in pieces]
    #y1 = [response for op, response, interval in pieces]
    y1 = [interval for op, response, interval in pieces]

    p1 = plt.plot (x, y1, label='test')
    plt.legend()
    plt.title ('AAAAA test')
    plt.xlabel('# of Operation'), plt.ylabel('Response time')

    #plt.hist(y1, 100)
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    analyze()
```

DATA FIle

```
    0             277.94                0.00
     1            277.94             6553.00
     2            277.94            32768.00
     3            277.94            32768.00
     4            277.94            45875.00
     5            277.94            13108.00
     6            277.94            26215.00
     7            232.93             6553.00
     8            277.94            13107.00
     9            232.93            39321.00
    10            301.94             6554.00
    11            232.93             6554.00
    12            277.94            13108.00
    13            232.93            19661.00
    14            236.93             6554.00
    15            285.94            19661.00
    16            232.93            32768.00
    17            277.94             6554.00
    continue......
```

Error (Python 2.7)

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "../scripts/plot_interval.py", line 27, in <module>
     analyze()
   File "../scripts/plot_interval.py", line 18, in analyze
     p1 = plt.plot (x, y1, label='test')
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 3154,  in plot
     ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1814, in inner
     return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 1425, in plot
     self.add_line(line)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 1708, in add_line
     self._update_line_limits(line)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 1730, in _update_line_limits
     path = line.get_path()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/lines.py", line 925, in get_path
     self.recache()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/lines.py", line 612, in recache
     x = np.asarray(xconv, np.float_)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 482, in asarray
     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
 ValueError: could not convert string to float: ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
```

Error (python3)

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "../scripts/plot_interval.py", line 27, in <module>
     analyze()
   File "../scripts/plot_interval.py", line 11, in analyze
     for d in data:
   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
     (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 0:  invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: try print the two arrays and post the results

Comment: I can run the script with the given example data. Could there be some sort of String / char in the data file?

Comment: I solved the issue, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest a very easy debug step:

Before returning the array, print the var `a` and see if there are strings that do not represent a valid float.

When you find them, you will need to know why they are there.

Comment: I found the reason that there is crash in the middle of data file.